# Remove Empty XML Elements - Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, automation, lxml

I am attempting to remove empty XML elements from an XML, but having an issue with the elements that have attributes but no text values. I can successfully remove the empty XML elements, but cannot preserve the elements with attributes in the final XML.  I would like to essentially clean up the XML and remove empty nodes with no text values altogether, but keep the nodes with attributes.

Below is the script I am using, along with the input and (desired) output XMLs....any assistance is most appreciated!

The Script:

```
from lxml import etree
import os

path = "C:\\users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\"

### Removing empty XML elements
tree = etree.parse(os.path.join(path,"my_file.xml"))

for elem in tree.xpath('//*[not(node())]'):
   elem.getparent().remove(elem):

with open(".//new_file.xml","wb") as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')) ## Removes empty XML elements, including the elements with attributes
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<nas:metadata xmlns:nas="http://www.arcgis.com/schema/nas/base"   
xmlns:mcc="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"    
xmlns:mdl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mdl/1.0" 
xmlns:mnl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mnl/1.0">
xmlns:lan="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
xmlns:lis="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lis/1.0">
xmlns:gam="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/gam/1.0">

  <mdl:metadataIdentifier>
    <mcc:MD_Identifier>
        <mnl:type>
          <gam:String>The Metadata File</gam:String>
        </mnl:type>
          <mnl:description codeList="http://arcgis.com/codelist/ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset"/>
         <mnl:address>
          <mnl:defaultLocale>
          </mnl:defaultLocale>
         </mnl:address>
         <lan:language>
           <lan:type>
             <lis:name>English</lis:name>
           </lan:type>
          </lan:language>
      </mcc:MD_Identifier>
      <mcc:contactInfo>
        <mdl:POC>
          <mnl:name>
            <lis:person>Tom</lis:person>
          </mnl:name>
          <mnl:age>
          </mnl:age>
          <mnl:status>
          </mnl:status>
        </mdl:POC>
      </mcc:contactInfo>
    </mdl:metadataIdentifier>
 </nas:metadata>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<nas:metadata xmlns:nas="http://www.arcgis.com/schema/nas/base"   
xmlns:mcc="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"    
xmlns:mdl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mdl/1.0" 
xmlns:mnl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mnl/1.0">
xmlns:lan="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0">
xmlns:lis="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lis/1.0">
xmlns:gam="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/gam/1.0">

  <mdl:metadataIdentifier>
    <mcc:MD_Identifier>
        <mnl:type>
          <gam:String>The Metadata File</gam:String>
        </mnl:type>
        <mnl:description codeList="http://arcgis.com/codelist/ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset"/>
      <lan:language>
        <lan:type>
          <lis:name>English</lis:name>
        </lan:type>
       </lan:language>
     </mcc:MD_Identifier>
     <mcc:contactInfo>
       <mdl:POC>
         <mnl:name>
           <lis:person>Tom</lis:person>
         </mnl:name>
       </mdl:POC>
     </mcc:contactInfo>
   </mdl:metadataIdentifier>
 </nas:metadata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml is your question is not well formed, but assuming that's fixed, try changing this line

```
for elem in tree.xpath('//*[not(node())]'):
```

to this:

```
for elem in tree.xpath('//*[not(node())][not(count(./@*))>0]'):
```

and see if it works.

Edit:

The edited XML in the question still isn't well formed. I tried to fix it and then applied the following:

```
xml_str = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<nas:metadata xmlns:nas="http://www.arcgis.com/schema/nas/base"   
xmlns:mcc="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mcc/1.0"    
xmlns:mdl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mdl/1.0" 
xmlns:mnl="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/mnl/1.0"
xmlns:lan="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lan/1.0"
xmlns:lis="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/lis/1.0"
xmlns:gam="http://standards.org/iso/19115/-3/gam/1.0">

  <mdl:metadataIdentifier>
    <mcc:MD_Identifier>
        <mnl:type>
          <gam:String>The Metadata File</gam:String>
        </mnl:type>
          <mnl:description codeList="http://arcgis.com/codelist/ScopeCode" codeListValue="dataset"/>
         <mnl:address>
          <mnl:defaultLocale>
          </mnl:defaultLocale>
         </mnl:address>
         <lan:language>
           <lan:type>
             <lis:name>English</lis:name>
           </lan:type>
          </lan:language>
      </mcc:MD_Identifier>
      <mcc:contactInfo>
        <mdl:POC>
          <mnl:name>
            <lis:person>Tom</lis:person>
          </mnl:name>
          <mnl:age>
          </mnl:age>
          <mnl:status>
          </mnl:status>
        </mdl:POC>
      </mcc:contactInfo>
    </mdl:metadataIdentifier>
 </nas:metadata>

"""
doc = etree.XML(xml_str.encode())
for elem in doc.xpath('//*[not(count(./@*))>0][not(normalize-space(.))]'):
    elem.getparent().remove(elem)
print(etree.tostring(doc, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8').decode())
```

The output I get from the above is the desired output in the question.

Comment: Hey, @Jack, I updated the XML to make it a valid format.  I tried your updated script, but it didn't do the trick.  I tried to "print(elem)" based on the condition stated, but it did not yield any elements.  Is it working on your end?  Thanks again for your continued assistance!

Comment: Thanks, @Jack, your solution works great on the input XML!  For what it's worth, I'm trying to apply the same script to a much larger file and it is still removing the elements with the attributes and their parent elements.  I'll have to continue to troubleshoot why that is, as the sample XML above follows a similar construct, but I will otherwise confirm your answer as the correct solution - Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of `[not(count(./@*))>0]`, you should be able to just use `[not(@*)]`. No need to count attributes.